# How do I find a control and pass it as a commandparameter

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

So I'm trying to pass my `Rectangle` as a `CommandParameter` because I wanna get it's X & Y properties because the goal is to move it when I press `W`.

How do I properly pass it as a CommandParameter?

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="W" Command="{Binding Forward}" CommandParameter="{ Binding RelativeSource= { RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                AncestorType={x:Type Rectangle}}}"/>
</Window.InputBindings>

<Window.DataContext>
    <viewmodel:BaseViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="PlayerArea">
        <Border Width="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="Green"/>
        <Border Width="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="Green"/>
        <Border Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Green">
            <Button Content="Connect" Width="100" Command="{Binding ConnectCommand}"/>
        </Border>
        <Border Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="Green"/>

        <Rectangle Width="50"
                   Height="50"
                   Fill="Red"
                   x:Name="localPlayer"/>

    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Comment: You may bind Rectangle"s properties to ViewModel and use/change it there instead of passing it to the CommandParameter.

Comment: @aepot Do you reckon I should create a seperate ViewModel for that?

Comment: `Rectangle` has no X and Y properties and your `Rectangle` is inside a `Grid`, so which coordinates do you want to change to _move_ it?

Comment: That`s up to you. You can use the existing one.

Comment: I was planning on using a Canvas and then changing the `Top` property

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario maybe you want to use a [`Canvas`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.canvas?view=netcore-3.1) instead of a `Grid`.

> Defines an area within which you can explicitly position child elements by using coordinates that are relative to the Canvas area.

You can bind the `Rectangle` as command parameter, but then you pass a view control to your view model, which should be avoided to maintain a clean separation of concerns. However it would not help here, because `Rectangle` itself does not have coordinates.

Nevertheless, you can create properties for the `X` and `Y` coordinates in your view model. Do not forget to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, otherwise these properties will not be updated in the user interface.

```
private double _x;
private double _y;

public double X
{
   get => _x;
   set
   {
      if (_x == value)
         return;

      _x = value;
      OnPropertyChanged(nameof(X));
   }
}

public double Y
{
   get => _y;
   set
   {
      if (_y == value)
         return;

      _y = value;
      OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Y));
   }
}
```

As your rectangle has a certain size, you have to compensate it to get the correct coordinates. You can do that in the view model, too, but I create a multi value converter as an example here, that is only used in XAML bindings.

```
public class SizeCompensatingCoordinateConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      return (double)value - System.Convert.ToDouble(parameter) / 2;
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      return (double)value - System.Convert.ToDouble(parameter) / 2;
   }
}
```

I used your example and adapted it for a `Canvas` using the converter to set the coordinates via bindings to the `X` and `Y` properties in the view model.

```
<Canvas x:Name="PlayerArea" Width="200" Height="200">
   <Canvas.Resources>
      <local:SizeCompensatingCoordinateConverter x:Key="CoordinateWithRespectToSizeConverter"/>
   </Canvas.Resources>
   <Border Width="25"
           Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}, Path=Height}"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           Background="Green"/>
   <Border Canvas.Right="0"
           Width="25"
           Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}, Path=Height}"
           HorizontalAlignment="Right"
           Background="Green"/>
   <Border Height="25"
           Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}, Path=Width}"
           Background="Green">
      <Button Content="Connect"
              Width="100"
              Command="{Binding ConnectCommand}"/>
   </Border>
   <Border Canvas.Bottom="0"
           Height="25"
           Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}, Path=Width}"
           Background="Green"/>

   <Rectangle Canvas.Top="{Binding X, Converter={StaticResource CoordinateWithRespectToSizeConverter}, ConverterParameter=50}"
              Canvas.Left="{Binding Y, Converter={StaticResource CoordinateWithRespectToSizeConverter}, ConverterParameter=50}"
              Width="50"
              Height="50"
              Fill="Red"
              x:Name="localPlayer" />

</Canvas>
```

This is not a perfect example that might fit all your requirements, but it should provide you the basics of binding coordinates even via a custom converter to view model properties and using coordinates in a `Canvas`. Now, you can directly read and set the `X` and `Y` coordinates in your `Forward` command.